# Mistake proofing web configuration

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, uri, asp.net-web-api2

After a long and exhausting troubleshooting ritual, it was found that a missing trailing '/' in a URI for a API configuration was the cause for the error.

`http://ab.com/xyz` instead of `http://ab.com/xyz/`

All other environments except Production were correctly configured, adding to the dismay.

What are some of the sensible ways - automated or not - to mistake proof this?

Comment: "Mistake-proof" sounds like a set of *very* custom logical rules.  I imagine you could write something which reads the config file, examines specific parts of it, and evaluates those parts against specific rules.  Which parts to examine and what rules to evaluate are all entirely custom so there's really no tool that would handle that for you.  (For example, a trailing slash may be required in one config value but not in another.  It depends on how those values are used.)  A more robust solution would likely be to validate in the code so that runtime errors are easier to track down.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any .net coding, but I am under the impression that .net applications typically use XML as the syntax for their configuration files. This suggests that you might want to use a XML schema validation engine to automate some semantic checks on the contents of the configuration files.

A Wikipedia article lists some of the more well-known [XML schema languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema_languages).